# "This is all now banned". Is this sentence referring to one single thing or does it refer to more than one thing?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language

This is from the BBC. [beauty salons](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-66271855)

**In the past, grooms were allowed to watch their bride get ready. Madina even remembers some men taking photos inside the salon. This is all now banned.**

The sentence **"This is all now banned"** drew my attention. The **"all"** in the sentence sounds like it refers to plural activities but then it is preceded by **"This"** instead of **"These".** It says **"This is all....."** instead of **"These are all....."**

So it kind of feels confusing. Does it refer to the issues in the previous sentence as a plural thing such as (watching the bride, taking photos) or does it refer to those things as one single thing.

In other words, since there are more than activity in the previous sentence, why does it not ask it in a plural way such as **"These are now banned"**, but instead uses **"This....."** which does not sound plural at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*All this*" is an idiomatic phrase for referring to things *collectively*. Saying "*this...all*", as in your example, is the same.

Your quote mentions at least 2 different, but related things - firstly, men were allowed to *watch* their bride get ready, and secondly that some had *taken photographs*. So, saying "all this is now banned" covers all of this, and perhaps other unmentioned activities, too.

Although something of a trope, British policemen of the 19th and early 20th century are often depicted as asking "*what's all this, then?*" as a way of querying suspicious goings-on.